# Trac issue/bug tracking software - is there a way to use git AND svn on the same trac installation

Tags: git, svn, trac

I've successfully installed Trac bug tracking software which has the ability to use SVN and GIT - however I am having problems setting up both types of repositories for the same trac installation.  The config seems to imply that there should be only one 'type' of repository for a trac install but this seems to fly in the face of the interface which implies that more than one type of repo can be added to the interface.

Anyone have this same issue?  I have been to google already and cannot find the search terms needed to address this specific issue.

EDIT

This is the error I get when trying to 'resync' the git repo
GitError: GIT control files not found, maybe wrong directory?

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you an use both Git and SVN in the same installation; [trac.edgewall.org](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser) is doing just that. [TracRepositoryAdmin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#Repositories) explains how to add multiple repositories through either the trac.ini config file, or the database (recommended).

Regarding the resync error, perhaps you haven't pointed `dir` to the `.git` directory. The issue discussed in [#11297](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11297) might be what you are experiencing.

Comment: Note: configuring it for Trac does not necessarily mean it's configured for your SVN or GIT client on PC side. It's just for having it in the timeline and source browser.